# Is there any way to see the categorical content of a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

If, for example, a SQL 'categorical' column measures extreme, high, medium, low or no risk, I would like to see those values as output from a SQL query. I can't find it anywhere.

Is it possible? Thankyou.

Comment: Are you looking for the values that are stored in the table?  Or are you looking for the possible values the column can take on?

Comment: The first one ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT categorical
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

May be you need this one?